# Error: new-PSSession:One or more computer names is not valid

Tags: powershell, updates, sccm

Back story:

I am working on a script that will be pointed at a Microsoft SCCM collection.  This script is meant to query for all members in the collection and do something.  So far I can restart specific services on all collection members, such as the SCCM service.  The next bit I am working on is uninstalling a patch from each member in the collection.

Something like this works to restart the service on each collection member:

```
foreach ($member in get-cmdevice -collectionname "A collection name"){Get-Service -ComputerName $member.name -Name CcmExec | Restart-Service}
```

The script:

```
foreach ($member in get-cmdevice -collectionname "Some collection name") 
{   
    $ession = new-PSSession -ComputerName $member
    Invoke-Command -Session $ession {wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:######/quiet /log /norestart} 
}
```

The resulting error:

> new-PSSession:One or more computer names is not valid

Trying to emulate the 1st script, by only adding the invoke-command, results in the script trying to uninstall the update from the local computer.

Thoughts?

Comment: you're missing a semicolon between `$Member` and `Invoke-Command`

Comment: Please re-format your code snippets (indent the lines with 4 spaces). Do not format code as quoted text (line beginning with `>`).

Comment: Done.  foreach, { on next line, $ession line, Invoke line, > on next line.

Comment: Adding the ; did not fix the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  Had to add

```
.name
```

after $member down in the session.  I was trying to pull the whole object / array in.